How to find multi-variable correlation?
I have a degree in engineering but no deeper knowledge in statistics so I'm wondering if anyone can point me the direction to find a solution to the following problem:

I have a set of input variables [A,B,C,...] and one output variable X that I would like to predict or at least estimate some probabilities about it. Let's use the example of estimating the amount of ice-cream sales (X) using a set of input data (temperature of the day (A), amount of tourists in the city (B), if it's raining or not (C), etc).

Issues here are:

perhaps a subset of the input variables (say for example C) does not correlate (or correlate weakly) with X but might have a strong correlation when combined with other variables (i.e. B and C combined might correlate strongly to X). Ex.: maybe the temperature of the day (variable A) alone doesnt help me predict the amount of ice cream sold (X), nor the amount of tourists in the city (B) currently. But when combining both (amount of tourists and temperature of current day, i.e. A and B) maybe I have a strong correlation to the sales amount (X).
input variables might be continous or boolean. Ex.: variable C (if it's raining or not) is boolean but might help me predict the amount of sales.
I am not sure if this is even called correlation because I am not necessarily looking for a linear relationship, but rather any possible valuable relationship. For example, X might tend to be within a specific interval when B comes closer to a specific value. That means, I would be interested on just a specific region of values from B. Whenever B gets far away from this region, it doesnt interest me anymore (i.e. does not matter its relationship to X). Ex.: maybe it is not interesting at all if the temperature of the day is above 35°C or below 15°C, because in both cases it is either too hot or too cold to go outside and have an icecream, so I am just interested in finding out, that whenever temperature falls within a specific range, the amount of icecream sold tends to be higher, but not interested if they still related to each other outside of those ranges.
I do not need to estimate a possible value of X necessarily for every input combination, but rather identify potential subset of input variables within a specific value range that might indicate a probable range of X. In other words, go through a dataset and try to find input values (maybe whole input, or maybe a subset by discarding some of the variables) that might indicate that this specific combination usually happens (more often than usual) when X is also within a specific range.Ex.: in days of low sales I do not want necessarily to know if it was because it was raining, or because temperature was too high or too low. I just wanna find possible combinations of input that might indicate that this specific day will probably have high sales, i.e. when temperature falls within a specific range, it's not raining and so on... (maybe some other variables D, E, F... are not even relevant so can be discarded as well).

I know this sounds like a multiple-step problem (and possibly not so easy to tackle here) but I would be glad if someone could point me to any kind of non-linear relationships that could help me out, especially with multiple variables.
Issue number 3 is for me the most critical one, because it blocks me from using some Co-variance matrix or pearson correlation, since the variables possibly are not linearly related. Ex.:
Issue number 4 also makes it complicated in the sense that I am not looking for a relationship that applies always, but rather find potentially interesting regions/combinations in the dataset.
I was considering using unsupervised learning methods, since I have a better background in AI than in pure statistics, but I havent found a suitable algorithm for it yet.
Any help is much appreciated.

Have you looked at modern end-to-end feature learning such as AEs for continuous or hybrid features extraction to flexibly possily your specified interval constrained nonlinear functional form instead of the old manual feature engineering way?
